# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'UserName' not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have written a program to display some details entered in one form in another.Like I have a UserRegisteration.jsp where I am entering few details and UserAccount.jsp which has to display some of the entered details.I have created a model object UserDetails which has all the details of a particular code.
When I am running the project I am getting the propertynotfound exception.I have checked everything and couldn't find the reason behind it.I have the getters and setters methods in my model class.And using auto-binding feature using @modelattribute.Kindly let me know if I missed any code.

UserDetails.java

```
package com.bindu.myBankcontroller;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserDetails {

private String UserName;
private String FirstName;
private String LastName;

private String EmailId;
private ArrayList<String> AccountType;
private ArrayList<String> gender;
private Long AccountNo;
private int age;
private String password;

Address address;

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    FirstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    LastName = lastName;
}


public String getEmailId() {
    return EmailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    EmailId = emailId;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAccountType() {
    return AccountType;
}

public void setAccountType(ArrayList<String> accountType) {
    AccountType = accountType;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(ArrayList<String> gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Long getAccountNo() {
    return AccountNo;
}

public void setAccountNo(Long accountNo) {
    AccountNo = accountNo;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}



}
```

Controller class,UserAccountController.java

```
package com.bindu.myBankcontroller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.bindu.myBankcontroller.UserDetails;

@Controller
public class UserAccountController {

@ModelAttribute
public void addingCommonObjects(Model model1) {

    model1.addAttribute("headerMessage", "MyBank, India");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/LoginForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {

    ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("LoginForm");

    return model1;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/userRegistration.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView submitRegistrationForm() {

    ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("UserRegistration");
    return model1;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/UserAccount.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView userAccountForm(@ModelAttribute("user") UserDetails user) {

    System.out.println("User name:"+user.getUserName());
    ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("UserAccount");
    return model1;
}


}
```

UserAccount.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

    <h3>Congratulations!! you have successfully registered</h3>

    <h2>Details submitted by you:: </h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td>${user.UserName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name :</td>
            <td>${user.FirstName}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name :</td>
            <td>${user.LastName}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

None of the related posts helped me in resolving this issue, so I have posted this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is cause by the way you are accessing your property in jsp,

```
${user.UserName}
```

should instead be

```
${user.userName}
```

Same for the other expressions, you should lower case the first letter.

Behind the scenes the *UserDetails* is introspected and a map of properties is created, but the keys are based on your getter/setter methods, so lowercased (userName, firstName, lastName). In your JSP EL you're passing the key, and it is not matching any property on account of case difference

Comment: yeah it worked.I missed it while understanding the concept.Thanks a ton.

Comment: np, glad it helped :)

Comment: @Hima Rayprolu, if the answer helped you, you might consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Your instance variables do not respect the java naming principles. Java variables should start with lower letter and use camel case capitalization.

Ex: **userName, firstName, lastName**,
and the corresponding getters would be **getUserName(), getFirstName(), getLastName()**.

If you have the instance variable defined like this the jsp *accessors* will be obtained by stripping the *get* (or *is*, if the method returns a boolean) suffix and lower the first letter of the remaining method name: **${user.userName}, ${user.firstName}, ${user.lastName}**.